# Question about the definition for Schwartz-Space regarding $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, schwartz-space

I am reading the book "Classical Fourier Analysis  by Grafakos" and did encounter some questions about the Fourier Transformation.

Disclaimer:
I am not that far in Analysis to be able to claim to understand Analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ very good. For that reason I am trying to first understand Fourier Analysis in $\mathbb{R}$ before $\mathbb{R}^n$.
But since the book is writen with $\mathbb{R}^n$ in mind I am trying to rewrite the definitions for $\mathbb{R}$.

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=:\partial_i f$

Let $\alpha=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n) \in \mathbb{N}^n$ and let $\partial1^{\alpha}f:=\partial_1^{\alpha_1}...\partial_n^{\alpha_n}f$

The in the chapter about Fourier transform the book starts with defining the class of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by

Definition:
A $C^{\infty}$ complex valued function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a Schwartz function if for every pair of multi indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$ there exists a positive constant $C_{\alpha,\beta}$ such that:
$\rho_{\alpha,\beta}(f)=sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}|x^{\alpha}\partial^{\beta}f(x)|=C_{\alpha,\beta}< \infty$.

I think that for $n=1$ the definiton is:
...if for every pair of Indices $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N_0}$ there exists a posiitive constant $C_{\alpha,\beta}$ such that:
$\rho_{\alpha,\beta}(f)=sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|x^{\alpha}\frac{d }{d x}f(x)|=C_{\alpha,\beta}< \infty$

Is that correct?

Edit 1:
My first version was a little bit wrong, as I saw in the comments, so here the corrected version:

$\rho_{\alpha,\beta}(f)=sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|x^{\alpha}\frac{d^{\beta} }{d^{\beta} x}f(x)|=C_{\alpha,\beta}< \infty$

Comment: you lost the beta on the power of d/dx. But yes

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thank you very much, I did add an Edit, I hope I got it right this time